# Thread diameter of hub

Tags: hub

I've got a rear hub Shimano 5353 with a freewheel,I want to change the wheel for the one with campganolo hub,I dont know whether my freewheel will suit campganolo hub
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Presumably the Shimano hub/freewheel has an ISO freewheel thread and the Campy hub has a Italian thread. These thread standards are close enough to interchangeable.

From [Sheldon Brown's Freewheel Page](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/freewheels.html):

> Italian: 1.378" x 24 tpi / 35 x 1.058 mm
>
> ISO: 1.375" x 24 tpi / 34.92 x 1.058 mm